# Quickly calculating centroid of binary numpy array

Tags: performance, python-2.7, numpy, vectorization, centroid

I have a numpy array of 0's and 1's (512 x 512). I'd like to calculate the [centroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid) of the shape of 1's (they're all connected in one circular blob in the middle of the array).

```
for i in xrange(len(array[:,0])):
    for j in xrange(len(array[0,:])):
        if array[i,j] == 1:
            x_center += i
            y_center += j

count = (aorta == 1).sum()
x_center /= count
y_center /= count
```

Is there a way to speed up my calculation above? Could I use numpy.where() or something? Are there any python functions for doing this in parallel?

Comment: you can also use `np.count_nonzero()` instead of the count variable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can replace the two nested loops to get the coordinates of the center point, like so -

```
x_center, y_center = np.argwhere(array==1).sum(0)/count
```

Comment: assuming array is an image it's vice versa y_center, x_center. Also could use np.argwhere(.).mean()

Answer (score 2):

You could also use [`scipy.ndimage.measurements.center_of_mass`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.center_of_mass.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np 

x_c = 0
y_c = 0

area = array.sum()
it = np.nditer(array, flags=['multi_index'])

for i in it:
    x_c = i * it.multi_index[1] + x_c
    y_c = i * it.multi_index[0] + y_c

centroid = int(x_c/area), int(y_c/area)
```

Thats should be the centroid of a binary image using `numpy.nditer()`